# After upgrading from Spring Boot 1.1.5 to 1.1.6, gradle build fails with "Duplicate library commons-io-1.3.2.jar" in the :bootRepackage task

Tags: java, gradle, spring-boot

I upgraded Spring Boot from 1.1.5 to 1.1.6, and after that, my (multi-project) build fails with:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':admin:bootRepackage'.
> Duplicate library commons-io-1.3.2.jar
```

All other tasks seem to have been successful (compileJava, compileGroovy, processResources, classes, jar, and distJar). I have one explicit dependency on the Commons I/O library in my build.gradle file:

```
compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-io', version: '1.3.2'
```

I'm using Gradle 2.1, but trying the build with 2.0 makes no difference. I ran gradle dependencies but it didn't reveal anything particularly interesting. Has anyone else seen this since upgrading? Reverting back to 1.1.5 solves the issue, so I'm guessing it's related to a new dependency in the Spring Boot jar(s) for 1.1.6. Any hints to a resolution are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you've found a bug caused by the fix for [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1475). Can you please [open an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/new) with the details of your dependencies so that we can track it down?

Comment: Thanks. This is the new issue:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1543

Comment: Posting Andy's response to my question about a workaround:

"I think you should be able to replace your **org.apache.commons:common-io:1.3.2** dependency with a dependency on **commons-io:commons-io:1.3.2** as the latter is a relocation of the former."